# App Inventor Slider : Setting it for whole values?

Tags: android, slider, app-inventor

How do I set the slider to increment by a whole number, not by a decimal value of .N? I can get the value to translate to a label, but I don't want it in decimal value.

This was my original reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P80FkfGvHWw

Edit:
[image: My Code As of Now For My Slider]

My value needs to be at 5 maximum... but I do not want to receive the decimal values at all. I eliminated most of the possible fractional values, but there are still some options.

Between 1-5, is there a mathematical way that can automatically round fractions to a whole number?

Thank you! (Please ignore the comment, that was for something else)

Comment: What is `App Inventor`?

Comment: @Der Golem, App Inventor is a programming software by MIT that makes a drag and drop environment via jigsaw puzzle form (so you know what connects properly) to program with to code.

Comment: It's to simplify beginners to help them understand logic. I just have not found a sufficient tool for OS X to develop for Android specifically.

Comment: Can someone please answer this question relevantly?

Comment: `I just have not found a sufficient tool for OS X to develop for Android specifically.` What about a serious **tool**, such as **Eclipse** or **Android Studio**? `Can someone please answer this question relevantly?` I seriously doubt that anyone here uses this `App Inventor`...

Comment: Eclipse constantly destabilizes my OS X- I've reinstalled OS X three times because it causes issues. I know it's for a fact Eclipse because the second time I installed my OS X, and then installed Eclipse, my Mac acted up two days right afterward and didn't even transfer data to the Mac yet.

Comment: Android Studio? I never heard of it. I'll look into it. Thank you Der Golem.

Answer (score 2):

[see the documentation](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/support/blocks/math.html#round)

> **round**
>
> Returns the given number rounded to the closest integer. If the
>   fractional part is < .5 it will be rounded down. It it is > .5 it will
>   be rounded up. If it is exactly equal to .5, numbers with an even
>   whole part will be rounded down, and numbers with an odd whole part
>   will be rounded up. (This method is called round to even.)

[image]

Probably also a good idea is to use **Do it**, see also the [Top 5 Tips how to learn App Inventor](https://puravidaapps.com/learn.php). You also can simplify your blocks a bit instead of using 3 times `set global wholeInt ...`